# pyminer for getblocktemplate/segwit?

Tags: segregated-witness

I'm trying to resurrect my simpleminer.py script, based on pyminer, for use with Bitcoin 0.13.2 but the changes to the code over the last few years are overwhelming. I found out how to use getblocktemplate using the excellent Python examples in the wiki (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate), but that doesn't explain what to do with the "segwit" stuff, e.g. the "default_witness_commitment" value.

can anyone point me to some documentation that has kept up with the code changes? right now it looks like I'm going to have to grok the source, and I'm not even sure I'm up to the task any more.